# Is there any voting weight decay through proxy vote?

Tags: vote-decay

when someone votes through proxy in 'system voteproducer proxy',

Is there decay on that?

The reason I ask you is, for example, in case of an account "giytcnjuguge"

"giytcnjuguge"has voted at 2018. 9. 16 and never refreshed his votes again. but there isn't any decays.. 
https://eosflare.io/tx/59c04b2c803347da4e2ed231ee1107105023ad349af3514a7b582b4a7005f27f

but most of cases, vote thorough proxy occur decays usaually!

Comment: decay is accomplished by giving more weight to more recent votes, and it happens regardless of the method you used to vote

Comment: Yes, that is the fact that I know... but, could you explain why "giytcnjuguge" has no decay since 2018.9.16?

Comment: how do you expect to detect decay? the vote value doesn't go down. newer vote values are higher making older votes implicitly weight less

Comment: @confused00 can I dm you?